# Libre Office Writer: Strike-out on delete rather than remove?

Tags: version-control, libreoffice, openoffice-writer, writer

We occasionally see revision-suggestions for documents (usually from our attorneys) where removed content gets color coded and has a strike through it. Added content also gets its own color coding.

I had always presumed that some specialty software was used to achieve such *versioning* effects, but one of our salespeople just received a document from their customer and it seems to be in that "mode".
When he tries to delete anything, it simply turns lime green and gets stricken out.

Is this a feature that can get turned on/off in Libre or Open Office?
If so, where/how?

Comment: BTW, I _did_ find the formatting settings for this feature in **Tools>Options>LibreOffice Writer>Changes**, but still have no idea how to enable/disable it.

Comment: **Ctrl+Shift+e** is how to disable it quickly. Chiming in, 2016,11,14

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Main Menu - `Edit` - `Changes` submenu

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Nik, the question is where it can be turned off, so this does answer the question.

Comment: This saved me so much frustration. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

This feature is called Track Changes and it allows you to pass documents back and forth and see who made changes. The feature is accessible under the **Edit** -> **Changes** menu. Within this menu are 6 items:

- Record
- Protect Records...
- Show
- Accept or Reject...
- Comment...
- Merge Documents...

I should mention I'm using `LibreOffice` Version 3.6.4.3 (Build ID: 2ef5aff), but this menu should be identical in previous versions as well as OpenOffice.

You can see other peoples changes by checking/unchecking the `Show` item. If you want to disable/enable the recording of changes you check/uncheck `Record`. Finally if you want to incorporate other peoples changes you check/uncheck `Accept or Reject...`.

Here are some additional resources to get you started if you want to actually do more than just disable this feature.

- [Collaborate Using LibreOffice Writer Changes and Comments](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/405303%3acollaborate-using-libreoffice-writer-changes-and-comments)
- [Recording and Displaying Changes](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Recording_and_Displaying_Changes)
- [Screencast demoing Track Changes](http://www.ilearnthings.com/2012/01/16/episode-11-tracking-libreoffice/)
- [Taming Apache OpenOffice - Tracking changes](http://www.taming-openoffice-org.com/newsite/?page_id=109)

Answer (score 3):

**LibreOffice** **5.4.1.2.0**

`Edit -> Track Changes -> Record` (uncheck Record)